# Doubt on regularity at "Minimal solutions of a semilinear elliptic equations with a dynamical boundary condition"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

In the paper [Minimal solutions of a semilinear elliptic equations with a dynamical boundary condition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782415001646) by Marek Fila, Kazuhiro Ishige, Tatsuki Kawakami, in Chapter 2 there is a construction of a sequence of functions
\begin{align}
u_{0}(x,t) = 0, \quad x \in \overline{\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}}, t>0
\end{align}
and inductively
\begin{align}
        u_{k}(x',x_{N},t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} P(x'-y',x_{N}+t) \varphi_{k}(y') d y' + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}} G(x,y) f_{k}(y,u_{k-1}(y,t)) dy \\
        &+ \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}} P(x'-y',x_{N}+y_{N}+t-s) f_{k}(y,u_{k-1}(y,s)) dy ds , \quad x \in \overline{\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}}, t>0
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}=\{(x',x_N):x'\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}, x_N>0 \}$ is the Half-Space, $P$ is the Poisson Kernel for the Half-Space, $G$ is the Green function for the Half-Space introduced in Chapter 1, and for $k=1,2,3,...$

\begin{align}
\zeta_k (x) = \zeta(2^{-k}x), \quad \varphi_k (x',x_N) = \zeta_k (x) \min\{\varphi(x'),k\}, \quad f_k (x,s)=\zeta_k (x) \min\{f(s),k\}
\end{align}
where $\varphi$ is be a nonnegative measurable function, $\zeta \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ such that
\begin{align}
        0 \leq \zeta \leq 1 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^{N}, \quad \zeta=1 \text{ in } B(0,1), \quad \zeta=0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^{N} \setminus B(0,2)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f \text{ is a nondecreasing continuous function in } \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } f(0) \geq 0 .
\end{align}
Later in Chapter 4, functions of the type
\begin{align}
z_k (x,t) = U(x,t)-u_k(x,t)
\end{align}
will be contructed, where $U$ is a classical supersolution (in particular $U(\cdot,t)\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+})$ ) and Theorem 3.1 will be applied on this functions $z_k(x,t)$.

The step I have difficulty with is the fact that Theorem 3.1 requires proving that the function $z_k(\cdot,t) \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+})$, so since $U(\cdot,t)\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+})$ it would be enough to show that
\begin{align}
u_k(\cdot,t)  \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}), \quad \forall k=0,1,2,3,...
\end{align}
I have focused on demonstrating that the called Newtonian potential
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}} G(x,y) f_{k}(y,u_{k-1}(y,t)) dy
\end{align}
is $C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+})$: if $k=0,1$ then this is true, while if $k\geq 2$ one way to prove this is proving that
\begin{align}
f_k (x,u_{k-1}(x,t))=\zeta_k (x) \min\{f(u_{k-1}(x,t)),k\}
\end{align}
is Hölder-continuous or Dini-continuous in the variable $x=(x',x_N)$. I tried by induction assuming that $u_{k-1}(\cdot,t)$ is Hölder-continuous, but I failed to see how to use the hypothesis that $f$ is a nondecreasing continuous function to prove the inductive step, i.e. that this implies
$f_k (x,u_{k-1}(x,t))=\zeta_k (x) \min\{f(u_{k-1}(x,t)),k\}$ to be Hölder-continuous or Dini-continuous. The difficulty lies in the fact that the composition of a nondecreasing continuous function $f$ with a Hölder-continuous $u_{k-1}$ does not guarantee that $f \circ u_{k-1}$ is Hölder-continuous, nor that $f_k (x,u_{k-1}(x,t))=\zeta_k (x) \min\{f(u_{k-1}(x,t)),k\}$ Dini-continuous. Is there another way to prove that $u_k(\cdot,t)  \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+})$ for all $k$?

Thanks in advance for your knowledgeable replies.